# JQuery code, works in version 1.5.2 but not in version 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JavaScript/JQuery code taken from [this tutorial](http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-game-development-lesson-1/)

When I use 1.5.2 version of JQuery, this code works absolutely fine. But when I use the latest version of JQuery (1.9.1), this code does not work. What needs to be changed for this code to work in the latest JQuery.

[Here is a version with JQuery 1.5.2](http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/147/index.html)

[Here is a version with JQuery 1.9.1](http://jsbin.com/ukagas/2/edit)

As you can see Jquery 1.5.2 works but not 1.9.1.

```
var canvas, ctx;
var circles = [];
var selectedCircle;
var hoveredCircle;

// -------------------------------------------------------------

// objects :

function Circle(x, y, radius){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------

// draw functions :

function clear() { // clear canvas function
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
}

function drawCircle(ctx, x, y, radius) { // draw circle function
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 35, 55, 1.0)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function drawScene() { // main drawScene function
    clear(); // clear canvas

    ctx.beginPath(); // custom shape begin
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 110, 110, 0.5)';
    ctx.moveTo(circles[0].x, circles[0].y);
    for (var i=0; i<circles.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(circles[i].x, circles[i].y);
    }
    ctx.closePath(); // custom shape end
    ctx.fill(); // fill custom shape

    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)';
    ctx.stroke(); // draw border

    for (var i=0; i<circles.length; i++) { // display all our circles
        drawCircle(ctx, circles[i].x, circles[i].y, (hoveredCircle == i) ? 25 : 15);
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------

// initialization

$(function(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('scene');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var circleRadius = 15;
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;

    var circlesCount = 7; // we will draw 7 circles randomly
    for (var i=0; i<circlesCount; i++) {
        var x = Math.random()*width;
        var y = Math.random()*height;
        circles.push(new Circle(x,y,circleRadius));
    }

    // binding mousedown event (for dragging)
    $('#scene').mousedown(function(e) {
        var canvasPosition = $(this).offset();
        var mouseX = e.layerX || 0;
        var mouseY = e.layerY || 0;
        for (var i=0; i<circles.length; i++) { // checking through all circles - are mouse down inside circle or not
            var circleX = circles[i].x;
            var circleY = circles[i].y;
            var radius = circles[i].radius;
            if (Math.pow(mouseX-circleX,2) + Math.pow(mouseY-circleY,2) < Math.pow(radius,2)) {
                selectedCircle = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    $('#scene').mousemove(function(e) { // binding mousemove event for dragging selected circle
            var mouseX = e.layerX || 0;
            var mouseY = e.layerY || 0;
        if (selectedCircle != undefined) {
            var canvasPosition = $(this).offset();

            var radius = circles[selectedCircle].radius;
            circles[selectedCircle] = new Circle(mouseX, mouseY,radius); // changing position of selected circle
        }

        hoveredCircle = undefined;
        for (var i=0; i<circles.length; i++) { // checking through all circles - are mouse down inside circle or not
            var circleX = circles[i].x;
            var circleY = circles[i].y;
            var radius = circles[i].radius;
            if (Math.pow(mouseX-circleX,2) + Math.pow(mouseY-circleY,2) < Math.pow(radius,2)) {
                hoveredCircle = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    $('#scene').mouseup(function(e) { // on mouseup - cleaning selectedCircle
        selectedCircle = undefined;
    });

    setInterval(drawScene, 30); // loop drawScene
});
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @Zeta I am not sure. In the Google Chrome console, it does not show any error or warning

Comment: @AnkurSharma: Zeta's point is *what result are you seeing* that says it "doesn't work." Any time you find yourself typing"Doesn't work" in a technical question, backspace over it and type *exactly* what it's doing, *exactly* what you think it should be doing, and *why* you think that is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have posted two live versions, so it is easy to see what is not working. In 1.9.1, it seems, the mouselisteners are not working.

Comment: is it broken on all browsers ? You may want to have a look a the support of layerX and layerY

Comment: @AnkurSharma: *"I have posted two live versions, so it is easy to see what is not working."* No, that's not how it works. We could easily observe **different** behaviors than the ones you're worried by and try to solve *those*. There's absolutely zero reason to leave people guessing, and even less to persist in doing so in the face of people who are trying to help you asking you questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery no longer blindly copies **all** properties of `Event` objects from the real event object to the one that jQuery provides, so these lines:

```
var mouseX = e.layerX || 0;
var mouseY = e.layerY || 0;
```

...are failing (always returning `0` for both `mouseX` and `mouseY`) in `mousedown` and `mousemove` handlers, because [the jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) doesn't have `layerX` and `layerY`.

jQuery makes the original event object available as `originalEvent`, though, so this fixes it:

```
var mouseX = e.originalEvent.layerX || 0;
var mouseY = e.originalEvent.layerY || 0;
```

[Updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ukagas/7) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ukagas/7/edit)

Or to be compatible with multiple versions:

```
var mouseX = e.layerX || e.originalEvent.layerX || 0;
var mouseY = e.layerY || e.originalEvent.layerY || 0;
```

[Updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ukagas/9) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ukagas/9/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
e.layerX
e.layerY
```

to

```
e.originalEvent.layerX
e.originalEvent.layerY
```

And that work :)

(http://jsbin.com/ukagas/3/edit)